# How to add an item from foreach to object array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-cloudformation

In my Code I have below code snippet

```
const accountEnv = 'Prod'
const accPermissionMap = {}
Object.values(Accounts).forEach(account => { const adminRole = ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `${account.account}-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + account.account + ':role/Admin')})
```

As a result, Inside the foreach loop, it will assign below values to the "account" variable when the loop is running.

```
ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `Prod-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + Prod + ':role/Admin')
ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `UAT-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + UAT + ':role/Admin')
ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `MT-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + MT + ':role/Admin')
ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `Dev-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + Dev + ':role/Admin')
```

I'm trying to

1. Add every ImportableRole to "accPermissionMap" as an object with a key.

So, after adding, "accPermissionMap" should be something similar to,

```
{
Key: Prod,  Value: ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `Prod-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + Prod + ':role/Admin')
Key: UAT,  Value: ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `UAT-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + UAT + ':role/Admin')
Key: MT,  Value: ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `MT-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + MT + ':role/Admin')
Key: Dev,  Value: ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `Dev-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + Dev + ':role/Admin')
}
```

Could someone please suggest a workaround?

Comment: *"I'm trying to..."*: Thank you for the code, but I see no attempt in that code to do either of the two points you list: There is no mention of `accPermissionMap`, nor `accountEnv` in the loop. What have you tried?

Comment: Also, please add the definition of `Accounts` and of `fromRoleArn`, specify what `this` is, provide the expected content of `accPermissionMap`. Please focus on one question only.

Comment: sth like? ```accPermissionMap[account.account] = ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `${account.account}-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + account.account + ':role/Admin')```

Comment: @trincot Question is edited as per your suggestions. Yes, in the loop i've not used any of the map or variable name because i'm confused how to use it. For that only, i need a workaround.

Comment: @cmgchess Thank you for your reply but it doesn't work

Comment: The desired output is not possible: an object cannot have twice the same key. Please also make sure the desired output uses the intended syntax. Are `Prod`, `UAT`, ... variables? And I repeat: please add the definition of `Accounts` and of `fromRoleArn`, specify what `this` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add each `ImportableRole` object to the `accPermissionMap` using the `account.account` as the key. Then, iterate over the keys of `accPermissionMap` and check if any of them match the `accountEnv` value. If a match is found, you can perform your desired action with the corresponding `ImportableRole`. Also, make sure you have the necessary import statements and that the `Accounts` object is defined correctly.

```
const accountEnv = 'Prod';
const accPermissionMap = {};

Object.values(Accounts).forEach(account => {
  const adminRole = ImportableRole.fromRoleArn(this, `${account.account}-Role`, 'arn:aws:iam::' + account.account + ':role/Admin');
  accPermissionMap[account.account] = adminRole; // Add each ImportableRole to accPermissionMap
});

// Check which ImportableRole item is equal to accountEnv
Object.keys(accPermissionMap).forEach(account => {
  if (account === accountEnv) {
    // If it matches, perform the desired action
    const matchedRole = accPermissionMap[account];
    // Do something with the matched role
    console.log(`Found a match for accountEnv (${accountEnv}) with role:`, matchedRole);
    // Perform your desired action with the matched role
  }
});
```

Comment: @Adrian Thank you so much for your kind assistance. To access the account, I've used as ${accPermissionMap[account] but the solution is spot on. Thank you for both of you

Comment: @ShanWave007 I just made some cosmetic edits to the post. The answer is down to Anmol.

Comment: thanks @AdrianMole to you too :) this is my first time responding to a post. Thank you for the minor adjustments. When I make my further contributions, I'll have these ideas in mind.